# How to build 4 codewords with a code distance of 5?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, code-generation

I wonder how can I construct 4 (distinct) codewords given the fact that code distance is 5. As far as I know that the code distance is the number of distinct bits between any 2 codewords. How to achieve this code distance for the 6 possible pairs from the 4 codewords available(of any bit length). I named, for example, codewords u, v, w, & x so d(u,v) = d(u,w) = d(u,x) = d(v,w) = d(v,x) = d(w,x) = 5. The code words must be in binary format i.e 00100 10011. I considered a code length of 10 to achieve this but still struggling to find a solution.

Comment: A code has *distance 5* if any two different codewords are at distance *at least* 5. It has *minimum distance 5* if the minimum distance between two different codewords is 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0000000000
1111100000
0000011111
1111111111
```

Comment: Is there a general algorithm for this problem? Given number of code words and minimum distance, find a code of minimum required length.

Comment: You can always use exhaustive search.